# The method setModel(TableModel) is undefined for the type Table

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

My purpose is to take information and display in the table.

For some reason I receive an error at this part

```
Table.setModel (DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

I can think just about that the setModel do not like the type of my "Table"

Here is the "Table and scollPane" code:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(429, 112, 380, 300);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

JTextArea Table = new JTextArea();
scrollPane.setViewportView(Table);
```

Here is the code for inserting information into the table

```
public SpendingsTrack() {
    initialize();
    table_load();
}

Connection con;
PreparedStatement pst;
ResultSet rs;
Connection con1;
PreparedStatement insert;

public void connect () {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unu","root","");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void table_load() {
    try {
        
    
    insert = con1.prepareStatement("select * from track2 ");
    pst.executeQuery();
    Table.setModel (DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    
    
    }catch (SQLException e3){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Something is wrong with the table");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't show what DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs) return.

Comment: `JTextArea Table = new JTextArea();` since when is a text area a table?

Comment: Classic naming `JScrollPane scrollPane`, weird unclear naming that makes no sense `JTextArea Table`.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I forgot to change it back... that was the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: You want a `JTable`, not a `JTextArea`

Comment: *`Table.setModel (DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));`* is NOT going to work. Why? Because you haven't assigned the result of the query to `rs`. [Thanks for using my software](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/22-resultset-to-tablemodel) but you should do so in a less compressed way and you must close db resources in try-with-resources or you're going to get leaks and unexpected behaviours